# woocommerce post_type conflict with existing post type

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

I have one product type created already in website via register_post_type and its type is post_type=product

I have already 20k items there and i want to keep them.

Now the thing is i want enable woocomerce here and it creates the same post_type, So what can be done to keep both without conflict?

Answer (score 0):

register a new post type and then change the post_type column of your existing entries in the posts table in the database.